# Float a control over a CView

Tags: mfc, cview

I've got an app that uses several `CView`-derived classes (actually `CScrollView`) to display document data. For one particular view, I want to add a fly-out edit box to add notes. That is, you'd see a tab at the bottom of the window labeled "Page Notes", and clicking on that would bring up the edit box. Clicking the tab while the edit box is visible would reduce it back to just the tab.

I thought I could use a one-tab `CTabCtrl` holding an edit box and just position it so that only the tab is visible initially. Capture the tab click notification and move the entire control, with edit box, into view. Clicking the tab again would move it back down so only the tab is visible.

Hosting the `CTabCtrl` on the `CView` is fine, and I can get it positioned correctly. The problem is that if the view is scrolled, the tab control is scrolled along with it, whereas I need it to "float" over the view and not be affected by any scrolling. I can move it back into place after the scroll, but the flickering is unsightly.

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish the "floating" effect? I mainly want the tab embedded in the view for maintenance, since it's the only view class out of the several in use that needs the "Page Notes" feature.

Should I just buckle down and put the tab in the view's parent window instead? I know it won't be affected by scrolling there, but I like the idea of keeping the tab as part of the view if possible.

Comment: If it's not supposed to scroll, shouldn't it be "outside" the scroll view, just like you have said? Perhaps, you need to split your view into two views?

Answer (score 1):

It sound like the tab is functioning like a button. You click the tab and a fly out edit box appears. You could use a modeless dialog. 
Select the "Page Note" and the modeless dialog comes up to edit your notes allowing you to scroll your view under the dialog.